# Парсинг видео ссылок Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

Как с помощью `Jsoup` или чего-то другого спарсить вот эту ссылку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
http://198.16.100.90/s/ba4d9966278620dfac643a7a61f46b65/uhd_4k/Thor.Ragnarok.2017.2160p.BluRay.SDR_720.mp4
```

С этой страницы например:
[Тыц](https://filmix.me/fantastika/118226-tor-ragnarek-2017.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это долгий процесс, поэтому буду краток.

1. Делаем post запрос на https://filmix.co/api/movies/player_data при этом нужно передать .data("post_id", [id фильма 118226]).data("showfull", "true").header("Cookie", [куки с сайта])
2. В полученном json достаем параметр "flash:"
3. Выбираем параметр с нужной озвучкой и декодируем файл с помощью uppod
4. Заменяем выборку качества в получинном файле "[,,1080p,720,480,]" на нужное нам